# Отправить сообщение по user id aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, бот

как я с помощью команды, могу с админ чата отправить сообщение пользователю в бота зная его tg id

Можно же как-то использовать команду и отправить например с помощью команды /send id текст

Comment: Если он начал общение с ботом, то `bot.send_message(chat_id, message)`

Comment: Возможно вы не так поняли, он начал общение с ботом, но я например хочу написать ему от себя текст, чтобы он ему пришел в бота, например я пишу в бота команду /send id человека и текст и ему приходит

Comment: Ну, сделать в боте хендлер на команду с аргументами.